# FFMPEG Batch script for windows to remove first 13 seconds and last 6 seconds

Tags: ffmpeg, video-editing

So I've been working at this the last 2 days trolling articles on here with many only getting me halfway to my answer. I have around 200 videos that all need to be batch converted. I only have windows at my perusal. I have successfully removed the first 13 seconds no problem. But the last 6 need to be removed from each file. My Latest iteration is:

```
for %%a in ("*.mp4") do set /a dur=(ffprobe -i "%%a" -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0") set /a trim=(dur-6 -sexagesimal) ffmpeg -t trim -i "%%a" "output\%%~na.mp4"
```

However when I run this I get "Unbalanced parenthesis." error. Full readout below:

```
C:\Users\Me\Desktop\FFMPEG Test Folder>set /a dur=(ffprobe -i "test.mp4" -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0") set /a trim=(dur-6 -sexagesimal) ffmpeg -t trim -i "test.mp4" "output\test.mp4"
Unbalanced parenthesis.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what ended up working

```
@Echo Off
SetLocal
Set "ext=mp4"
Set "opts=-v quiet"
Set "opts=%opts% -print_format "compact=print_section=0:nokey=1:escape=csv""
Set "opts=%opts% -show_entries "format=duration""
If Exist *.%ext% (If Not Exist "Trimmed\" MD Trimmed)
For %%a In (*.%ext%) Do Call :Sub "%%~a"
Exit/B

:Sub
For /f "Tokens=1* Delims=." %%a In (
    'C:\ffmpeg\bin\FFProbe %opts% %1') Do (Set/A "ws=%%a-6.00" & Set "ps=%%b")
rem If %ws% Lss 20 GoTo :EOF
Set/A hh=ws/(60*60), lo=ws%%(60*60), mm=lo/60, ss=lo%%60
If %hh% Lss 10 Set hh=0%hh%
If %mm% Lss 10 Set mm=0%mm%
If %ss% Lss 10 Set ss=0%ss%
C:\ffmpeg\bin\FFMpeg -i %1 -ss 00:00:13.0000 -to %hh%:%mm%:%ss%.%ps:~,3% -filter:v "crop=950:720:170:0" -r 24 -c:a copy "Trimmed\%~1"
```